# Android TextView OverLapping

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a top bar for my app that shows the users level, coins. So i have an image view that displays the coin icon and a textview that displays the number of coins, if the number gets high it overlaps the image rather than pushing back the image and keeping everything aligned, is there a way to do that?

Comment: please give the xml layout

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your layout XML this is pure guesswork, but I'm assuming these two views are in a RelativeLayout. If so, add to one of them an attribute like this:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/otherViewId"
```

Options available are `layout_toLeftOf` `layout_toRightOf` `layout_above` and `layout_below`.

Post your layout XML and I'll update this with a better answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the relative layout then you can use the z-index attribute of views to manage the ordering.